# Can I replace a toilet bowl myself?

Tags: toilet, plumbing-fixture

Normally, we'd pay a professional, but -- given the circumstances -- currently we loath bringing a stranger into the house. Likewise, finding anyone *willing* to go into a stranger's how to replace their toilet may be a problem too.

Is it something I can do myself -- with the help from the rest of the household? The current one is by Toto, and we're no longer "in love" with the pricey brand -- can I order a different one, or is that likely to increase the amount of work to the point of insurmountable?

For example, will the bolts holding the current bowl fit right into the new one, or is that not at all a given, and we should order the exact same model?

Or is a professional pretty much required anyway and we may just as well get a different design?

Comment: Home RenoVision DIY has a great channel with lots of video tutorials  This one's perfect for what you're looking for. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54eT2NXechM

Comment: Thanks, this was quite useful indeed. In the video he sets the wax-seal into the drain first and then "aims" the toilet into it. Our toilet's instructions were different -- attach the seal to the toilet first, then "aim" it into the drain -- and we followed that. But it seems to work -- and things are still dry around it two days later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

You will just need to remove the bolts that are at the bottom of the bowl and then raise the toilet up.  I recommend flushing it first as it'll be lighter. 
ALso have a trash bag handy. Although you have flushed the toilet, there's usually still some water in it. I recommend one person lift the toilet up and another person put the bag under the bowl to catch any water that may run out.

Then you'll need to scrap the wax ring off of the pipe in the floor.

Then install a new wax ring in the same location as the previous one. Do not press on it.

Then install your new toilet over the bolts and tighten them.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance. So, can I just as easily install a different model, or are the bolts unlikely to fit and I should get the same one?

Comment: Welcome If your replacement toilet has bolts that comes with it, then use those. Otherwise use the same ones that you currently have.

Comment: What about the ones protruding from the floor? Will the replacement just fit over them, or am going to have to make new holes, etc?

Comment: In case it wasn't already blindingly obvious, don't reuse the wax ring either.  I've replaced toilets (although with varying success) so you can too.  Just keep a close eye out for leaks.

Comment: To answer your specific question, the bolt spacing (between) is standard. The only variance you'll find is what's called the "rough in", which is the distance from the bolts to the back wall. 12" rough in is super standard. 10" and 14" are quite rare.

Comment: Depending on the age of the hose that supplies the tank, you'll probably want to replace it too. While you're there, you might want to replace the shutoff. There's a terrifying variety of sizes to choose from, so measure what you've got before you go shopping. (Only the connection to the tank is standard.)

Comment: You can also improve your life a little with a "bucket flush". Turn off the supply to the tank. Flush everything out of the tank. With at least a gallon of water in a bucket, dump that quickly into the bowl. If you've done it right, you'll end up with very little water in the bowl and trap below. If you have a wet/dry shop vac, you can suck up residual water out of the tank and trap. You can also use a sponge, but you won't empty the trap as thoroughly.

Comment: Be careful not to break them, the pieces are RAZOR sharp and can literally slice you to the bone if things go really sideways

Comment: Thanks to all -- yes, it proved easier than I was afraid it will be.